# Can't change root password in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, passwords, root

I am trying to change the root password in my Ubuntu system but I am getting an error. I disabled password prompt when calling `sudo`. So I can execute root commands (eg. `sudo apt-get install`) without typing root password.

```
ashot@ashot-desktop:~$ sudo passwd root
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

Comment: Have you tried just `sudo passwd` ?

Comment: Yes, the same error

Comment: What about `sudo -s -H` (to launch a sub-shell as root) followed by `passwd`?

Comment: Again the error

Comment: Is the root filesystem r/o?

Comment: How to check it?

Comment: `sudo su -` to obtain a root shell and change the password there

Answer (score 1):

The root account is [locked by default](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) in Ubuntu. When `sudo` asks for a password, you give it your user's password, not root's. This works because your user is in the `sudo` group and therefore has permission to run commands as `root`. If what you want is to reset your password, just run

```
passwd
```

If you have [enabled the root account](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Enabling_the_root_account) in Ubuntu and want to change that password, [boot into recovery mode](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword), log into a "root shell prompt" and reset there.

1. Remount the `/` filesystem read/write

   ```
   mount -o rw,remount /
   ```
2. Reset the password

   ```
   passwd
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As one of the comments on your question suggested, there is a quite high probability that your  root filesystem, "/" might be mounted read-only.

Try this command to see if it is the case:

```
sudo touch /testfile
```

if you get something like "can not create" or alike, you might want to try this command:

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount /
```

I have had reasonably high percentage of success, but sometimes it just doesn't fix the situation, forcing you to reboot. Trying it is easier than a reboot for sure.